# Printing a word document with image exceeding the margin

Tags: printing, microsoft-word-2007

If a word document with certain dimensions of margin has an image that exceeds the margin and is printed, will the part of the image that lies beyond the margin not be printed?

P.S. I'm using Microsoft office 2007.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens? Hint: print preview.

Comment: Margin doesn't mean printer won't (attempt to) print out of it. However majority of printers can't print "bordereless", there will be a white stripe on the edges.

Comment: Print preview does show the entire image, including the part outside the margin. I have to print more than 100 pages and there are several pages with images extending beyond the margin, not too close to the edge of the page. I think it would probably include things outside the margin because Headers and Footers are provisions of the word itself which lie outside the margin of the document. But I need confirmation before I either get them printed with the images cut off or taking the herculean task of editing them all. @DavidPostill

Comment: This is going to vary by printer and as that information has not been given, there is no correct answer besides: Print the document once to test and then fix as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the margin that you set in the word processing application and then there is a physical print margin depending on your printer. The margin in the application of course can be changed and the printer will print beyond this if there is something in that margin, for example header and footer.

Some printers can print true "bordereless" but most consumer grade printers will have a non printable margin, creating a white border. Even if you place the image beyond this limit the printer will not be able to physical print it and it will be cut off. This is dependent on your printer.

Try printing a page and see what your printer does.

Comment: The shop I'm going to visit has a line printer. Can you tell me what dimensions of margin a usual line printer could have?

Comment: I know that .25 inch is a safe bet for almost all printers.  I have been able to print up to about .18 top and bottom and .25 left and right on a laser. I'm not sure what the margin would be on a line printer.  I would recommend you just give the shop a quick call and tell them how close your image gets to the page and ask if that's printable by their line printer.